# Git Bash and text files with different encodings

Tags: windows, git, mingw, git-bash

Windows 7 x64; Git for Windows 2.5.2
In the session of Git Bash working I can change (manually) the options of Git Bash as required: to switch the character set. So, Git Bash correctly displays not english (cyrillic, for example) text either ANSI or UTF-8, but not both at the same time:

[image]

[image]

Whether it is possible that Git Bush would determines the encoding of the text file and switches own character set (in the Options window) for the correctly displaying the content of files with any encoding?

Answer (score -1):

```
git config --global core.quotepath false
```

Comment: so what? where is different?